# How to integrate posting likes on particular a post in facebook using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used https://developers.facebook.com to generate like button. But this button is for only facebook pages to be liked. I want to implement functionality of posting likes on facebook post using facebook c# sdk. I write below code -

```
 dynamic userTokenResult = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
    {
       client_id = strAppID,
       client_secret = strSecret,
       grant_type = "client_credentials"
   });
   dynamic res = client.Post("me/og.likes", new
    {
       @object = "https://www.facebook.com/yourpagename/photos/photoid/?type=3&theater"
   });
```

I am getting below error -
(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.